# caret package equivalent of randomForest.getTree

Tags: r, random-forest

I've been using randomForest.getTree to give me a text representation of each tree in my forest but have recently switched to the caret package to train the forests (method='rf'). How can I either get an object that randomForest.getTree understands (since caret is allegedly using the same underlying code) or print out the trees in some other analogous way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just figured it out:

```
library(caret)
.... #load data
model <- train(x,y,method='rf')
getTree(model$finalModel)
```